# Mysql row values as columns with count(*)

Tags: mysql, reverse

I have a table with below structure and i am trying to use the row values as columns with their value as number of occurrences.

```
|  date     |order|status|
-----+-----+----------------
| 2018-05-22|    1|  closed|
| 2018-05-22|    2|  closed|
| 2018-05-22|    3|  closed|
| 2018-05-22|    4|  open  | 
| 2018-05-22|    4|  open  |
```

Output:

```
|  date     |closed|open|
-----+-----+----------------
| 2018-05-22|   3  |  2|
```

When i use following query to get the count(*) value i get an error... "invalid use of group function"

```
select date,
  max(case when `status` ='closed' then count(*) end) closed,
  max(case when `status` = 'open' then count(*) end) open
from orders where date ='2018-05-22' group by date,status
```

Appreciate help to fix it...

Comment: you groub by "status" and this is missing in the selection

Answer (score 0, accepted):

How about the following?

```
select
  date,
  sum(case when `status` ='closed' then 1 else 0 end) closed,
  sum(case when `status` = 'open' then 1 else 0 end) open
from orders where date ='2018-05-22' group by date
```